# UnhandledReportRenderingException in SQL Reporting Service happening randomly

Tags: .net, sql-server, reporting-services

Hi:
one of our customers are having this exception randomly. We put in some re-try code and keep-alive code, yet it still happens. 
So I am looking at the SQL log our customer sent us. And I saw this.

So basicaly, one of the report has no data in certain field. would that be the cause of that problem?

```
library!ReportServer_0-15!150c!10/11/2010-11:50:22:: i INFO: RenderForNewSession('/CMSm5/PharmaPac_Live/Custom/Documents/Purchase Order.Pharma.2008')
processing!ReportServer_0-15!150c!10/11/2010-11:50:23:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 9., ;
 Info: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 9.
webserver!ReportServer_0-15!62c!10/11/2010-11:50:23:: i INFO: Processed report. Report='/CMSm5/PharmaPac_Live/Custom/Documents/Purchase Order.Pharma.2008', Stream=''
library!ReportServer_0-15!13ec!10/11/2010-11:50:50:: Call to GetReportParametersAction(/CMSm5/PharmaPac_Live/Custom/Documents/Purchase Order.Pharma.2008).
library!ReportServer_0-15!13ec!10/11/2010-11:50:51:: i INFO: RenderForNewSession('/CMSm5/PharmaPac_Live/Custom/Documents/Purchase Order.Pharma.2008')
processing!ReportServer_0-15!13ec!10/11/2010-11:50:51:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 9., ;
 Info: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 9.
library!ReportServer_0-15!13ec!10/11/2010-11:50:58:: Call to GetReportParametersAction(/CMSm5/PharmaPac_Live/Custom/Documents/Purchase Order.Pharma.2008).
library!ReportServer_0-15!13ec!10/11/2010-11:50:59:: i INFO: RenderForNewSession('/CMSm5/PharmaPac_Live/Custom/Documents/Purchase Order.Pharma.2008')
processing!ReportServer_0-15!13ec!10/11/2010-11:50:59:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 9., ;
 Info: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 9.
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be used in a conditional expression in a text box or othrr control. Or in a group/sort/filter expression.

So most times it's Ok until some condition or event happens and it then it looks for a non-existent column.

Sorry to be a bit vague

It's also possible that the underlying RDL is slightly corrupt too: can you redeploy?

Comment: yes, the RDL is deployed. So you recommend what? redeploying?

Comment: @user480838: delete and redeploy. It is a bit random and unscientific but it's worked for me once or twice before.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a field in a dataset that correspons to a column that no longer exists in the source stored procedure. The field is probably not used in the report anymore, because if it was used, you would get a real error when running the report.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error for bad rdl

```
<DataSets>
  <DataSet Name="testDataSet">
    <Fields>
      <Field Name="ID">
        <DataField />
        <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
    </Fields>
```

as you can see - DataField element is empty. The most strange is that such RDL is displayed by VS report designer preview but is not displayed in the ReportViewer as local report and by Reporting service in the web browser window.
after DataField has been properly filled and report redeployed to the reporting

```
<DataField>ID</DataField>
```

error has gone